# Why does isinstance returns false after dynamic instance creating?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

I have a problem while trying to create and instance based on the given dictionary.

My current code:

```
class Number(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def evaluate(self):
        return self.value

    def to_dict(self):
        return self.value

class ArithmeticNode(object):
    OPERATORS_TO_CLASSES = dict(map(lambda cls: (cls.OPERATOR, cls),
                    ArithmeticNode.__subclasses__()))

    def __init__(self, val1, val2):
        self.val1 = val1 if isinstance(val1, ArithmeticNode) else Number(val1)
        self.val2 = val2 if isinstance(val2, ArithmeticNode) else Number(val2)

    def to_dict(self):
        v1 = self.val1.to_dict()
        v2 = self.val2.to_dict()
        return {self.OPERATOR: [v1, v2]}

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(d):
        cls_dict = ArithmeticNode.OPERATORS_TO_CLASSES
        def create_node(d):
            nonlocal cls_dict
            if isinstance(d, dict):
                for operator, (left_val, right_val) in d.items():
                    cls_inst_to_create = cls_dict[operator]
                    value_1 = create_node(left_val)
                    value_2 = create_node(right_val)
                    return cls_inst_to_create(value_1, value_2)
            else:
                return d
        return create_node(d)

class AddNode(ArithmeticNode):
    OPERATOR = '+'
    def evaluate(self):
        return self.val1.evaluate() + self.val2.evaluate()
```

When Im doing:

```
a = AddNode(3, AddNode(5, 3)) # Everything works just perfect
d = a.to_dict() # {'+': [3, {'+': [5, 3]}]}
c = ArithmeticNode.from_dict(d)
print(c) # <__main__.AddNode object at 0x7fac20def908>
# Trying to check if this is still the instance of ArithmeticNode
isinstance(c, ArithmeticNode) 
> False
```

So my question is: why does isinstance returns False in this case, when:

```
a = AddNode(3, AddNode(5, 3))
isinstance(a, ArithmeticNode)
True
```

Sorry if it is obvious for you, but I can not find out why it works like that.

Comment: `OPERATORS_TO_CLASSES = dict(map(lambda cls: (cls.OPERATOR, cls),
                    ArithmeticNode.__subclasses__()))` is invalid. `ArithmeticNode` does not exist yet, so you cannot ask for its subclasses. Please provide [MCVE].

Comment: Well, that's strange. I was using jupyter notebook and there I got no error with this line, and code was executing as always, while using other python IDLE it throw an exception in this line. Thanks anyway. I fixed it with moving this to a static method and return it as a method result. Now everything works just fine.